# In Django Factory Boy, is it possible to specify custom FactoryOptions for a certain instance?

Tags: python, django, database, factory-boy

I'm writing unit tests for a Django app which use `factory_boy` test fixtures. In some cases, one fixture might try to create an object that was already created by another fixture, which leads to error messages similar to the following:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "lucy_web_sessiontype_title_c207e4f8_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (title)=(Postpartum Doula Support) already exists.
```

To avoid this, my first inclination is to write a `try..except` block, like so:

```
try:
    SessionTypeFactory(title='Welcome')
except psycopg2.IntegrityError as e:
    pass
```

However, it seems like it would be more elegant to use the `django_get_or_create` option described at http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orms.html#factory.django.DjangoOptions.django_get_or_create.

However, as far as I can tell from http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#factory.FactoryOptions, options specifie in the factory's `Meta` class will apply to *all* instances, whereas I would only like it to only apply to this instance. Is it possible to specify these options in the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc is slightly misleading. What is documented in the `FactoryOptions` section is the list of options available in the `class Meta` part.

In your case, you could go with the following code sample:

```
class SessionTypeFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.SessionType
        django_get_or_create = ['title']

    # your fields here
```

This will perform a `SessionType.objects.get_or_create(title=fields.pop('title'), defaults=fields)` every time you create an instance.
Since you have a `unique` condition on the `title` field, you can safely put that behavior in place at the `SessionTypeFactory` level.

Comment: Indeed the `title` field is unique, but others aren't, and the `get_or_create()` applies to any `**kwargs` passed into it; in the end I worked around the problem by just using `SessionType.objects.get_or_create()` instead of the `SessionTypeFactory`.

Answer (score 1):

After perusing the source code a bit, it seems from [this line](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/blob/2d735767b7f3e1f9adfc3f14c28eeef7acbf6e5a/factory/django.py#L158) in the `DjangoModelFactory` class definition that this is not possible. The class contains the following class method:

```
class DjangoModelFactory(base.Factory):

    @classmethod
    def _create(cls, model_class, *args, **kwargs):
        """Create an instance of the model, and save it to the database."""
        manager = cls._get_manager(model_class)

        if cls._meta.django_get_or_create:
            return cls._get_or_create(model_class, *args, **kwargs)

        return manager.create(*args, **kwargs)
```

From this, it seems that `django_get_or_create` is a class attribute and not an instance attribute, so it is not possible to specify `django_get_or_create` per instance. Please correct me if I'm wrong!